# Can Ethereum transaction (calling contract function) fail for reasons other than assert()/require()/revert() or gas issues?

Tags: exception, transactions, ethereum, solidity, evm

When running a private Ethereum network not requiring gas for transactions, can a contract function transaction fail for some "unpredictable" issue, other than explicit invocation of assert()/require()/revert(), for example dividing by 0 or some other issue with EVM or beyond EVM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- division by zero
- integer overflow/underflow in Solidity 0.8+ (previous versions let the number overflow, 0.8 throws an exception)
- accessing out-of-bounds array index
- message call (aka internal transaction) to an address that does not implement the called function (might have been selfdestruct or changed implementation behind a proxy)

These I could think of right now. I'm sure there's more examples, generally runtime errors cause by some logical mistake.

Comment: Thank you. I suppose in all those cases a transaction would still be created on the blockchain but in failed status.

Comment: @AndCode That's correct.